# How to Merge this Data-frames in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, row

I have 3 Data-frames of Following Shapes: 
(34376, 13), (52389, 28), (16531, 14)

This is the First Dataframe which we have:
[image]

This is the Second Dataframe which we have:
[image]

This the Third Dataframe which we have:
[image]

Now, as I have mentioned the shapes of all the Dataframes, the main task is we have to merge this on the Accession Number \

DF1-has the exact 34376 Accession which we want.

DF2- has around 28000 Accession which we want. This basically means that the remaining Accession of that table we don't want.

DF3- has around 9200 Accession which we want

How can we, merge all these 3 DF's on Accession Number, so that we get the extra columns of DF2,DF3 merged with DF1 on Accession Number. Also, we can see that DF2 has 52389 columns, so if there are same Accession Numbers repeated in DF2, we still want to merge it, but the rows of DF1 should be repeated while merged with the extra rows of DF2 and same with DF3. The Accession where no values are available in DF2/DF3 but present in DF1, the rows should become Null.

Comment: It'd be better if you can attach the images here itself rather than having it as links

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function

```
pd.merge(pd.merge(df1,df2,on='ACCESSION_NUMBER'),df3,on='ACCESSION_NUMBER')
```

or

```
df1.merge(df2,on='ACCESSION_NUMBER').merge(df3,on='ACCESSION_NUMBER')
```

or

You could use the `reduce` class from `functools` library

```
reduce(lambda x,y: pd.merge(x,y, on='ACCESSION_NUMBER', how='outer'), [df1, df2, df3])
```